# PowerShell add-ons

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

What are the complete steps for installing and/or adding an Add-on to a profile?  (Ex. ISE ScriptingGeek) (PowerShell v4.0)

I have tried the following:

- downloaded and unzipped `ISEScriptingGeek-master` in `C:\Users\Fname.Lname\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\` directory.
- added the `get-command -Module ISEScriptingGeek` to my profile.
- ran the following command - `get-command -Module ISEScriptingGeek` and restarted PowerShell ISE.

I do not see the Add-ons dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing steps to every add-on is not feasible in this format because every custom module can have different steps.

With regards to `ISEScriptingGeek` [add-on](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/scripting/1729/ise-scripting-geek-module/), the command you are putting in your profile is wrong, it should be:

```
Import-Module ISEScriptingGeek
```

You can verify it works first by just running that command in a PowerShell session.

Comment: I ran command and received the following error:  Import-Module : The specified module 'ISEScriptingGeek' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module 
directory.

Comment: I then changed the name of the unzipped folder from ISEScriptingGeek-master to ISEScriptingGeek.  And then I was able to run the command with success.